# Cerrar partial view popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo una vista parcial como popup la cual, **le puse una x para hacer click y cerrar la ventana**, **pero también deseo cerrar el popup de la siguiente manera: al hacer click fuera del popup debe cerrarse.**

El código que tengo es el siguiente:
Con esto creo el popup desde el index

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade in">
    <div class="modal-content" >
        <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #337ab7;border-color:#2e6da4;color:#fff;">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dissmiss="modal" onclick="cerrarModal();">&times;</button>
            <h5 class="modal-title" >Proveedor</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="resultado"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

javascript

```
<script>
    function cerrarModal() {
        $(function () {
            $("#myModal").modal("toggle");
        });
    }
</script>
```

No me funciona por que algo debe estar mal. Me ale el siguiente error
[image: errores]

Al parecer estoy usando materialize modal cuando lo que quiero es usar bootstrap modal.

Layout

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

<script src="~/scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

View index

```
<head>
<title></title>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="~/Content/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="~/Content/css/action-btn-wrapper.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: ¿`#modal` o `#myModal` se llama el `DIV` que quieres que tenga la extensión modal?

Comment: @Davlio #myModal ya corregí pero no funciona

Comment: `$("#myModal").modal("close");` intentaste con ese parámetro `close`

Comment: @Davlio No cierra la vista partial popup, probé el script tanto en la vista index como en la partial view pero no ha funcionado.

Comment: Te indica algún error la consola del explorador. Ejecuta y dime que te devuelve `console.log($("#myModal").length);` en la consola.

Comment: console.log($("#myModal").length)
VM73:1 1
undefined

Comment: El modal no es un componente de JQuery UI ? Has linkeado este aparte de JQuery ?

Answer (score 1):

Ya logré solucionarlo tenia un error de sintaxis el intellisense del Visual Studio lo hacia con error.

Tuve que modificar esta línea de código

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dissmiss="modal">&times;</button>
```

Por esta

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
```

En cuanto al cerrar haciendo click fuera del modal ya esa funcionalidad lo trae bootstrap modal.

Comment: ¿`Bootstrap Modal` o `Materialize Modals` estás usando?. Inicialmente pensé que era de `Bootstrap Modal`, pero al poner la imagen de error indicaba que estas usando `Materialize Modals`.

Comment: @Davlio, Al parecer asi es lo estoy usando sin saber como por mi falta de experiencia pero en el layout tengo bootstrap pero en la vista index tengo marerialize, voy a modificar la  pregunta poniendo el código del layout y de la vista index

Comment: Pueda que tengas conflictos en estilos y javascript, como ahora.

Comment: ¿`<button type="button" class="close" data-dissmiss="modal">&times;</button>` es diferente a `<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>`?

Comment: @Davlio Así es con la correción que hice puedo cerrar el modal con la x que puse en el código.

Comment: @Davlio en conclusión tengo que hacer varias modificaciones he encontrado clases con el mismo nombre y eso me esta perjudicando, eso genera el conflicto.

Comment: Solo te podría decir que verifiques el impacto y determina cual de ellos vas a usar `Bootstrap` o `Materialize`.